# Creating user session with Java in SAPUI5

Tags: java, spring, session, sapui5

I have SAPUI5 application where I am using Shell and I have created user login form. Also i have all the necessary user data stored in data base. I want to create user autentification session, by using Java, Java Spring or maybe there is another good alternative to do this in SAPUI5? After autentification I want to keep user loggined in.

Comment: You could use any standard J2EE means of creating an authentication session, it should be completely decoupled from the used UI technology

Comment: Do you plan to use a RESTFul back end. In this case REST services needs to be stateless. Using a login form capture the credentials. Then there are 2 options.

  Send the credentials with every request.
  Send the credentials and generate a token. Then send the token with every request.